# PhoneGap PushPlugin Foreground vs Background State

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

Using the PushPlugin, in both iOS and Android, it seems the callback using the foreground field is not able to distinguish between the situation when the push notification was received while the app is in the foreground and the situation when the app is in the background.

Would appreciate any insight.